# PHP: Pass variable hidden to another website

Tags: php

Website `b.com` should send data to `a.com` like this `http://a.com/tracking_script.php?code=342284240&tracking_id=893459234`.

However `b.com` should do this hidden. `b.com` does get the `tracking_id=893459234` from the visitor but the `code=342284240` is a secure code that only owner of `a.com` and `b.com` know. Because not anybody should be able to call the `tracking_script.php`

Simply put: How do I send data from `b.com` to `a.com` without the knowdledge of the visitor? So HTML Post, AJax etc. is not possible.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid the client seeing it, just do HTTP POST or HTTP GET from the PHP script.  If you want security, make `a.com` implements SSL.

Comment: @merlin2011 I don't only want the client not to see it, it should be impossible to get the data from the client side. How can I do HTTP POST or HTTP GET from a PHP Script. I don't get it

Comment: @user3630453, PHP runs entirely on the server side. The only information that gets passed to the client is whatever the server chooses to reflect back to the client. Here is a [simple example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) of using PHP curl to make a `GET` request.

Answer (score 2):

Store the code value in a database table that both sites can access, associate it with the tracking ID, and use only the tracking_id as the parameter in the URL.

```
http://a.com/tracking_script.php?tracking_id=893459234.
```

Then within tracking_script.php query the database to find the code associated with the tracking ID.